# Python: how to split a nested numpy array and use each in encryption method

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array which looks like this for example but a lot larger.

```
[[1, 3, 6, 2, 6]
 [11, 4, 3, 6, 3]
 [4, 4, 1, 5, 8]]
```

What I would like to do is get each nested array from the numpy array and add it for encryption. Trouble I am having is I can't manage to get multiple arrays from the numpy array and encrypt it, but it also needs to be converted into a list for encryption.

Here is my code:

```
array1 = dataset1[2] #gets the index of numpy array which would be [4, 4, 1, 5, 8]
array1 = array1.tolist()
public, private = paillier.generate_paillier_keypair()

encrypted_list = [public.encrypt(x) for x in array1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly this should work. Otherwise please state the expected output.

```
arr = np.array([[1, 3, 6, 2, 6],[11, 4, 3, 6, 3],[4, 4, 1, 5, 8]])
public, private = paillier.generate_paillier_keypair()

encrypted_list = []

for subarr in arr:
    encrypted_list += [public.encrypt(x) for x in subarr]
```